# JSFiddle Code does not translate into page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a heck of a time implementing this code into a site. I managed to get it going on JSFiddle, but I'm fairly new to most Javascript, and need a little clarification about how to link to JSQuery within the code on the page itself.

The site I'm uploading this into has a separate tag space for HTML, CSS and JS.

I'm running it with JQ 3.3.1. Can someone help me? I'm not sure if I'm missing a proper header with the JQ link in it, or what I'm missing. Thank you!

[JSFiddle Link HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/d3f60em0/16/)

```js
var timeout;
$('#cf').mouseenter(function () {
 var i = 0;
 var loopLength = $('img').length - 1;

 for (i = 0; i < loopLength; i++) {
  (function (i) {
   timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
    var currentImg = $('img.active');
    var nextImg;
    if (currentImg.next().length == 0) {
     nextImg = $($('img')[0]);
    } else {
     nextImg = currentImg.next();
    }
    nextImg.addClass('active');
    currentImg.removeClass('active');

   }, i * 5000);
  }(i));
 }
});

$('#cf').mouseleave(function () {
 clearTimeout(timeout);
 $('img').removeClass('active');
 $($('img')[0]).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#cf {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.active {
  opacity:1;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
<img class="active" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/i1s6f64stg71m47/cat02.jpg?dl=0" alt="Still Testing" /> 
<img class="" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x7iciwysri2wp5p/cat01.jpg?
dl=0" alt="Testing" />
<img class="" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/j32l5doxt0mwccn/cat03.jpg?dl=0" alt="Testing" />
</div>
```

Comment: even your snippet here says `$` is not defined. Make sure you have included jQuery

Comment: I realized I had it set to onload in my JSFiddle file. Adding a $(document).ready(function() { to the head of my JS fixed everything. I feel so stupid. ♥